# How to create save function for custom Gutenberg style block?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I need to create an extra style for WP Gutenberg Gallery block with a custom look and feel for front-end.

I'm trying to create custom style using wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle(). But for my goal, I need to use a custom save function.

Can I do it? Or maybe exist any another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to set this style inline? If it's just pure CSS you could include it in your theme or a plugin, inspecting the elements to figure out how to target specific elements. Each block has a specific class that identifies what kind of block it is, so you can only affect the gallery block using that class.

Comment: @WebElaine The method `wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle()` provide me the choice for style choosing meanwhile I add gallery block, it is very useful for me. But also I need to change the output layout and add extra classes to items.

Comment: Ok, for changing more than just CSS - actually changing HTML such as adding classes - you'll want to look into Block Filters. Try the Gutenberg Handbook and see if that helps: https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/